# AVQueuePlayer and multiple video playback and time ranges

Tags: ios, video, avqueueplayer

Somewhat new to ios programming.  Trying to use AVQueuePlayer and playing multiple videos in a list.  I have searched and have not seen a relevant example to what I am trying to achieve.  This is a question that is probably easily answered if somewhat could point me in the right direction.

What I am trying to do is really play videos in a list in sequential order.  So looking at the AVQueuePlayer and AVPlayerItem should seem to fit the bill.  I get how you can play multiple videos back to back with this, as most of the examples show how this is done.  What I want is to load a player item and to restrict it to a certain time within the file. For example, I would load a video file that is 3 mins long and only want to see the time of 1:20 to 1:35.  All the examples I have seen load the entire file.  There has to be a way of doing this, and I have not seen a good example of this yet.

I also want the ability for the AvPlayerItems to possibly be the same video file but they are playing different time ranges from the video file.  So in essence I am playing video time ranges in a list from any number of video files, but those video files could be the same source file in the list. For example:

A list of video and times to play

```
(seq    Video            Time)

1      video 1          0-30 secs   ---
2      video 2          45-60 secs  ---
3      video 3          120-130 secs  ---
4      video 2          3-12  --- 
5      video 3          30-40 ---
6      video 1          31 - 40
```

I have looked at apple developers reference for AvQueuePlayer and have not figured it out yet.  I'm sure some of you experienced guys out there have already done this and can point me to some good examples.

Comment: I've to play back to back videos and for that i'm using AVQueuePlayer. I've created items and 've added them in the queue. then i called queue.play(). But i don't know how to setup the view or the frame and therefore, the videos are not played or showed on the screen. How did you do that?? Kindly help. Thanks @Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching and watching WWDC videos from apple, the answer to my problem is to use AVComposition which will allow you to use multiple video source and compose them into a track that you can play back in whatever order you would like.

A good example is to watch the WWDC 2010 videos in itunes and watch the session named Editing Media with AVFoundation.  Within the presentation there is a good example project that they use called AVEditDemo.  It will give you the example code that you need to get going.